# How to generate time series given its autocorrelation?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, autoregressive

How can I generate a stationary Gaussian Random sequence/series that have the given autocorrelation?
I have found that Autoregressive model can do the job but How to decide the order and coefficient of the AR model?

Comment: Given the autocovariances, you can get the corresponding AR coefficients by solving the [Yule-Walker equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Yule.E2.80.93Walker_equations).

Comment: There is one problem, the given autocorrelation function is continuous (said the random series is sampled from continuous signal); if I try to sample this function value, the matrix and vector will be very large; and then Matlab seems to solve the `a=R^(-1)r` incorrectly. What can I do now?

Comment: I don't know. Posting the autocorrelation function that you mention may help others to give you an answer.